# What review am I missing?

Tags: support, reviewing

I have for weeks now been wondering why do I always see a certain number of reviews pending but when I go check the reviews' queues there are none.

Today it got worse when on the main page of the site I see 6 review pending :

[image]

And when I go on the review page the number becomes 8, however all review queue are empty :

[image]

Am I missing something ? Is there anything in the 10k tool that allow me to review items aswell and that I wouldn't have noticed ?

Comment: I never see that number at all! (even though I do have a Review button) Is that something that appears above 10k or something?

Comment: @Simon, there's an under-10k version that just shows suggested edits. It then starts showing all reviews once you hit 10k.

Comment: [Related from Meta.SE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239582/review-flag-count-is-still-wrong)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you skip any? If you skip a review, the existence of the review in the queue hasn't gone away. However, their presence in *your* queue runs (which are what the counts on the left side of the page you linked are based on) has been removed.

For example, I just did some reviews on a single queue over on another site, cleared straight through the suggested edits queue but I skipped two. Now the count at the top is two higher than the total number of items I see in queues, as Suggested Edits is listed as "0" since from my perspective as a reviewer I've cleared that particular queue.

Comment: That is entierly possible. Is there anything about the wrong number in the notification or should I just avoid skippind reviews ?

Comment: @WizLiz The notification tells you how many reviews are left on the site, period. We were looking into some changes that'll change the icon to reflect whether or not *you* as a user had reviews left, but the number will still stick around since it still indicates "I may have skipped some stuff but there's still stuff that needs someone's attention".